# Add Bootstrap Validation Errors Using Ajax Data & jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I get the following json error containing validation errors after doing an ajax request.

> {"errors":{"name":["The name field is required."],"description":["The description field is required."]}}

I am catching the errors using the javascript function below.

```
function formErrorsHandler(formWithElements, errorsForFormElementsJson) {
    console.log(errorsForFormElementsJson);
}
```

How do I make the form elements go red and perhaps display the element validation error message?

Can I use  [validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) to achieve this?

My form layout is as follows:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    ....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I eventually came up with :-)

```
function formErrorsHandler(form, errors) {

    $("label.error").remove();
    $('.error').removeClass('error');

    form.find('input, textarea, select').each(function(){
        var error = errors[$(this).attr("name")] ? errors[$(this).attr("name")] : null;
        if(error) {
            $(this).addClass("error").after('<label class="error">' + error + '</label>');
        }
    });
}
```

Please let me know if you can recommend any optimizations.